# "Error in main glxinfo is not installed. Please install mesa-utils package" when trying to install PlayOnLinux

Tags: playonlinux

I am currently trying to install League of Legends using PlayOnLinux, but every time I do I get this error:

> Error in main
>   glxinfo is not installed. Please install mesa-utils package

What should I do to fix this? I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make sure mesa-utils is installed:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out when I get the chance. I honestly tried looking all over for this and couldn't find it. You guys are life savers!

Answer (score 17):

Just open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```